# TCP Time out while fetching MetaData for Radio Streaming in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, timeout

I am creating an Radio app which will stream from the various different URL's.

Now while fetching the stream from the url's we also want the content that is which song is playing on i.e metadata.

Now for this i run another thread in a TimerTask that  will create the HTTP connection say like after every 40 seconds.

While using the simulator for OS 5 and above there is no problem but when i run the same thread for two to three iterations the metadata is recieved consistently but afterwards we got the TCP time out exception and this halts the over all system and device even losts the internet connection.

Can you please suggets any alternatives which can solve the problem.

I am also sharing the code that will get the metaData from the streaming URL.

```
class metaData extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean metaDataCheckBit = false;

            StreamConnection streamConnection = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
            HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection)streamConnection;
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Icy-metadata", "1");
            int httpStatus = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (httpStatus==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String mint = httpConnection.getHeaderField("icy-metaint");
                InputStream inputStream = streamConnection.openInputStream();
                int length = Integer.parseInt(mint);
                int b = 0;
                int count = 0;
                while(count++ < length){
                    b = inputStream.read();
                }
                int metalength = ((int)b)*16;

                if (metalength <= 0) return;

                byte buf[] = new byte[metalength];
                inputStream.read(buf,0,buf.length);
                final String metaData = new String(buf);
                final String streamTille = 
                    metaData.substring(14, metaData.indexOf("StreamUrl")-2);
                System.out.println("Stream Title--------"+streamTille);

                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            titleRf.setText(streamTille);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in meta data...."+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not closing the connection. I don't know if this can cause the problem, though. Try closing streams and connections in a finally clause.

Comment: Thanks Smith it worked after closing all the streams !!!

Comment: Lol, good thing it worked. In BlackBerry there's a limited number of simultaneous connections. After several connections left open you were hitting the limit and thus the timeout when trying to open a new one.

Comment: yupss....hey can you do me one more favour , have you integrated twitter in BB?

Comment: Nope. Never worked with Twitter in BB.